# .htaccess file returning 404 error when redirecting the root folder to a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

i am at my wit's end with this one.

I have a .htacces file which i'm using to redirect certain roots to files.

For example:

`example.com/` to `example.com/home.php`

`example.com/subdir/` to `example.com/subdir/home.php`

This is working great for my subdir redirect but my root redirect to home.php throws up a 404 error and then redirects me to my site's 404 eorr page.

This is my .htaccess file (i've left everything in just incase another rule is throwing things off).

```
RewriteEngine off
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#Alter the default time zone for the site
SetEnv TZ Europe/London

#set the RewriteBase
RewriteBase /

#Redirect from root to home.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?$
RewriteRule (\/)?$ home.php [L]

#Redirect from /subdir to /subdir/home.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir\/?$
RewriteRule ^subdir(\/)?$ subdir/home.php [L]

#Removing .php from the end of file paths
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

#Forcing https://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI}

#Redirect to 404 error page
ErrorDocument 404 /page_not_found.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ "https://example.com/page_not_found.php" [R=301]
```

What should i be doing to get example.com and example.com/ to redirect to example.com/home.php?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in after the comments `#Removing .php from the end of file paths`
Do comment your own code and paste this. It might help you

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for responding. That's got me a step in the right direction. It now redirects from `example.com` and `example.com/` however it still fails for `https://example.com` and `https://example.com` any ideas?

Comment: Can't say any further bro but that was working for me thats why i have shared with you :)